# Open a child window to work like alert box in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-3

I want to open  a  child window to work like alert box in Firefox. and  user should close the window before proceeding with any other operation. 
I want to do this because in Firefox the alert box title displays the ipaddress and I want to customize it.

Comment: Write it by your own. What have you tried?

Comment: Use one of the many modal dialog box libs. http://code.google.com/p/submodal/ or one of the numerous jQuery solutions

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, another window does not seem like a reasonable solution. There are many JavaScript plugins that will give you a modal overlay within the same page (more analogous to an alert box).

Maybe have a look at:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

or

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/X5DuY/) of a modal dialog box I wrote in response to another SO-question.